# what is the command to make an existing directory under version control using git?

Tags: git

what is the command to make an existing directory under version control using git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a git repository of a specific directory you would change to the directory you wish to create a new git repo for and do this:

```
git init
git add --all
git commit
```

That will create a git repository for the directory you are in, add everything in that directory (recursively) to the initial commit and then commit it.

A great link to get you started with git is [this one.](http://progit.org/book/)

Answer (score 2):

This will be one of the first steps of virtually any git tutorial, but here you go anyway:

Change into the directory and run:

```
git init
```

Then you need to add (stage) files and create your first commit.